# Spacebar causes search in Dropdown to close in Select2

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a PHP script which generates HTML which looks like this

```
<td class="param_item_value">
<select data-placeholder="Select..." class="paraAuswahl chosen-select select2-hidden-accessible" name="S_ListenArt" id="S_ListenArt" data-sql-filename="" size="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="Cake" selected="">Cake</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
    <option value="Pizza Royale">Pizza Royale</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 258px;">
<span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-S_ListenArt-container">
    <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-S_ListenArt-container" title="Cake">Cake</span>
    <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
        <b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>
</span>
```

The problem is, when you type into the Textbox to search for a specific item and press spacebar to search something like "Pizza Royale" which has a space in the name, the dropdown closes and the selection gets resetted.

I am using V4.0.0. Is something wrong with the HTML generated? Or do I have to initialize the Select differently?

Comment: Are you saying you're generating the `span`s via PHP?

Comment: The above HTML will not be helpful, as you have added the content, what select2 generates after a call. So add up actual content, what you have added in php?

Comment: The `span`s are not generated via PHP. I generate the `select`s and the `option`s with PHP.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Please let me know if you have found a solution.